# Problem replacing characters in a Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I'm just starting to get to grips with Regular Expressions.  My first task is to remove all the characters in a string except a-z (upper and lower case), 0-9, and the characters - \ . : and ,

So I tried

`objInstance.mystring.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\- .:,]", "")`

However, this still removes the hyphen and the backslash.

I suspect its the placement of the \  but some guidance would be helpful here.

Comment: Double the backslash, you need to escape it. (You may need to add 2 more since you are in a string but I'm not sure)

Comment: Yes I am already doubling the backslash, but it wasn't displayed as such when I posted originally. I've edited the post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash, as well as the hyphen. These are characters that have meaning in the regex so you need to escape them to have the actual character being monitored.

`[A-Za-z0-9\\\-.:,]` should be the correct regex. There's also a space in yours, there's no mention of it in your question so I removed that as well. There's also a `^` character in your regex. This signifies the start of a String, again as there was no mention of this in your question, I removed it in the regex.